# Convert an specific value of an array of objects to string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var users = [{
  user_id: 26795,
  social_id: null,
  type: 2,
  sport_id: "1",
  name: "G3 One"
}, {
  user_id: 84854,
  social_id: null,
  type: 2,
  sport_id: "1",
  name: "fd"
}, {
  user_id: 84855,
  social_id: null,
  type: 2,
  sport_id: "1",
  name: "Third Users"
}];
```

how to convert user_id to string

```
var strArr = users.map(function(e){
     console.log(e.user_id.toString());
     if(e.user_id) {
         e.user_id.toString();
     }
     return e;
});
```

The `user_id` value should be converted to `string` by using the `map()` method.

Comment: `users.forEach((e)=>{e.user_id=e.user_id.toString();})`

Comment: @Alax: Can you please review the answer posted by me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May avoid using arrow functions because its not supported in older browsers and IE11. You should be fine by using the return value inside the callback function:

#### > [Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgkd89s6/)

```
var users = [{
  user_id: 26795,
  social_id: null,
  type: 2,
  sport_id: "1",
  name: "G3 One"
}, {
  user_id: 84854,
  social_id: null,
  type: 2,
  sport_id: "1",
  name: "fd"
}, {
  user_id: 84855,
  social_id: null,
  type: 2,
  sport_id: "1",
  name: "Third Users"
}];

users.map(function (item) {
    item.user_id = item.user_id.toString();
    return item;
})

console.log(users);
```

Comment: Why use `.map` and not `.forEach`? (_They have the same browser compatibility_) For each would replace the value, whereas Map would return a **new array**

Comment: @AlekseySolovey please read the requirements on the question carefully. The user want to use `map`.

Comment: Aleksey and lin you both are correct. but i'm using .forEach as map has browser issue

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1 = [{user_id: 26795, social_id: null, type: 2, sport_id: "1", name: "G3 One"},
{user_id: 84854, social_id: null, type: 2, sport_id: "1", name: "fd"},
{user_id: 84855, social_id: null, type: 2, sport_id: "1", name: "Third Users"}];

array1.map(x => x.user_id = x.user_id.toString());
console.log(array1);
```

[Fiddle Link Here](https://jsfiddle.net/qL17azvw/2/)

Comment: "it should return same array object"

Comment: Same array object means ?

Comment: Any reason behind minus please !

Comment: @AlekseySolovey: I think above code is what user looking for, right ?

Comment: (_not my downvote_) (I'm not the one who asked a question) Apparently there is a requirement to use `map`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey: Yes I know you didn't asked, you have pointed so asked you to confirm the output. I'm not blaming you for minus.

Comment: with `.map` you need to return the array: `array1.map((x) => {x.user_id = x.user_id.toString(); return x;});`